# Cron deamon written in shell

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell, cron

I'm looking for a script in bash or ksh, that would do ... more or less ... the same as crond.
The situation is, that our system administrator suddenly denied the use of crontab to all regular users (with no exceptions) and I really do not want to log in to several servers every day just to execute some scripts.

I have a workaround - I wrote a script on my laptop, that uses ssh keys to log in to servers and execute scripts, but when I leave on vacation (or get fired) I won't be able to execute it - and I certainly won't give my private ssh keys to anyone..

So the idea is to run a script in nohup on each server, that will check a config file and execute tasks in it at defined days and times .. just like crond does.

I also thought about some kind of "jumping at viruses", that would first execute the script and then schedule next execution of themselves.

I estimate I would need approximately 2-3 hours to write it in bash .. but I don't want to reinvent a wheel, so if anyone already has something like this ... can you post it please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: … or you could **talk to** your system administrator and explain your business need for the ability to run scripts on a schedule from an unprivileged account.

Comment: thanks ... I did that, the reply was "no exceptions"

Comment: The idea of you running scripts after being fired sounds fairly illegal.

Comment: Sure ... however the output of these scripts is mailed to ~200 distinct users .. and this functionality should be preserved even if I  get fired :).
Anyway, I already wrote the crontab script myself ... so I no longer need it